# Do parents have a right to obtain a copy of all worksheets (non-tests) their child will receive for the year in a public school via e-mail?

Tags: united-states, education

Do parents have a right to obtain a copy of all worksheets (non-tests) their child will receive for the year in a public school electronically to assess/audit it?

If not, how can they point out bad things such as your movement from one concept to another is too slow, you're not moving at all or this curriculum is too repetitive?

If a school doesn't e-mail that to a parent, there's absolutely no way to be accountable. If they hand it in person, it would be hearsay and non-ownership.

How can education be public if it's just handed to students, and when a parent complains this is too slow being taught, the teacher could say, yours is hearsay. What evidence do you have I assigned that worksheet for homework?

Comment: What is the purpose of this question?

Comment: Schools are accountable to parents through the school boards, but can you imagine how difficult it would be to manage if individual teachers had to constantly adjust their curriculum based on parent perceptions? Because I might complain to the teacher that something is being taught too fast - Should they speed up for you, or slow down for me?

Comment: What if parents have a right to receive the materials but do not have a right to criticize the pedagogical structure of the curriculum?

Comment: @phoog Given that the question is tagged for the United States, under what circumstances could that possibly be the case?

Comment: @bdb484 it does seem unlikely.  I can imagine that a school district struggling to deal with parental attempts to micromanage their children's education might restrict direct access, however.

Answer (score 1):

At the federal level under FERPA, parents have the right to [inspect and review](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-34/subtitle-A/part-99/subpart-B) [education records](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-34/subtitle-A/part-99/subpart-A/section-99.3). I don't know what you mean by "worksheet", so it may or may not be an education record. Under any reasonable interpretation of the term it is a "record", but to be an "education record" it must be directly related to a student and maintained by an educational agency or institution or by a party acting for the agency or institution, for example "the answers of a student". It excludes records that are kept in the sole possession of the maker, are used only as a personal memory aid, and are not accessible or revealed to any other person except a temporary substitute for the maker of the record, and also excludes grades on peer-graded papers before they are collected and recorded by a teacher. In my youth we would receive sheets with math problems that we had to solve and hand in, which may have been retained – as long as the sheets were retained by someone in the school system other than the teacher, they would be "education records" (had the law existed at the time).

The actual purpose of this law is to allow students and their parents to inspect the basis for grading, and to allow access to the infamous "permanent record". It is not related to the political purpose of criticizing lesson plans, but one can of course use such information in that manner. Whether or not parents, or anyone, has a legal right to access lesson plans for some public commentary purpose is a matter of local school policy. The legal remedy for dissatifaction with educational policies is to write to your legislature and run for the school board.

Comment: education records are for example the tests and grade papers. They are **not** all teaching material to achieve such - which is what worksheets, assignments, or homework fall under that is not graded.

Comment: No, *any* record kept by the system that is "about" the student are education records. As per the definition of "education record". Homeworks are especially capable of being education records.

Comment: I was a bit unclear I guess: The handed-in part of the homework done **by the student** is reviewable, but generally the **assignment (sheet)** or the teaching material are not reviewable in this fashion. As in: you if the task is *solve 1+1*, that part can not be demanded review on (e.g. was it appropriate?), only the answer by the student is relevant.

Comment: Homework is not necessarily retained by the school, and anyway the question seems to be asking about having access to educational material before it is presented to the student, at which point it is not yet an educational record, for the purpose of evaluating whether the curriculum meets the parent's expectations.

Answer (score 1):

Parents do not have a right to inspect all educational materials because parents do not have the right to direct the education of their child.  Parents who wish to do this should homeschool their children or pay for their education directly themselves.

Public education means education financed by public tax dollars.  It does not mean anarchy of education by making the entire curriculum public and subject to scrutiny by every parent.

As to your standards of evidence...

> [Hearsay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hearsay), in a legal forum, is an out-of-court statement which is being offered in court for the truth of what was asserted. In most courts, hearsay evidence is inadmissible (the "hearsay evidence rule") unless an exception to the hearsay rule applies.

Hearsay means more or less trying to testify that someone told you something versus knowing the thing directly, not that you didn't have copies of documents in advance.